Postgres Local Prefixed vs Nonprefixed Index
Oracle has global indexes, Postgres does not. So far so good.
Oracle then has local prefixed and nonprefixed indexes and Oracle makes a deal of this difference, even in V19: Oracle Docs
I don't really understand why Oracle makes that difference and I can only explain it with 'lazy programming' to myself, but that's not the question here.
My question is: Is it ever useful in postgres to prefix an index for other than these obvious reasons:

Having the partitioning key as prefix in the index is useful to you, as the sorting in the index is useful to you
Having the partitioning key as prefix in the index is useful to you, as the partitioning key can have many different values


Reading up on Oracle's nomenclature, a prefixed index seems to be an index that has the partitioning key as leading column or columns.
I don't think that there is anything special about a prefixed index. If you need it for performance, create it. If not, don't.
Here is an example: imagine a large table, range partitioned by year on a timestamp, so that old data can be discarded easily. If you need to search data by that timestamp quickly, you may will need an index on the column to avoid a sequential scan of a whole partition. Voila, a prefixed index; nothing special about it.
The more important distinction is if an index contains the partitioning key or not, regardless if the partitioning key is in the leading column or not. With a local index (PostgreSQL only has those), you cannot enforce uniqueness across partitions, so you can only create a local unique index on a partitioned table if it is unique by definition, that is, it contains the partitioning key.
The Oracle documentation you quote says that "With a prefixed index, the likelihood to get partition pruning is much higher than with a non-prefixed index". But that is baloney. You get partition pruning if you have the partitioning key in your WHERE condition, and an index cannot influence the WHERE condition that a query may use.
To sum it up, I also don't know why Oracle makes this distinction. The Oracle documentation says that with a prefixed index Oracle can use the index for partition pruning, but I don't see why that should make a huge difference.

TYVM for your thoughts on the matter!
